# How to remove arraylist item and then update listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

```
ListView listView;
Activity activity;
public ArrayList<Tasks> tasks;
View v;

public TaskAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Tasks> tasks)
{
    super(activity, R.layout.presenterlayout, tasks);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.tasks = tasks;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView taskTitleTextView;
    public TextView taskDescriptionTextView;
    public TextView taskDueTimeTextView;
    public CheckBox checkBox;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.presenterlayout, null, false);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.taskTitleTextView = (TextView)      v.findViewById(R.id.taskTitleTextView);
        holder.taskDescriptionTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskDescriptionTextView);
        holder.taskDueTimeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskDueTimeTextView);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        holder.taskTitleTextView.setText(tasks.get(position).getTasksTitleString());
        holder.taskDescriptionTextView.setText(tasks.get(position).getTasksDescriptionString());
        holder.taskDueTimeTextView.setText(tasks.get(position).getTasksDueTimeString());
        holder.checkBox.setId(position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(holder.checkBox.isChecked())
                {
                    System.out.println("postion: " + position);
                    if(tasks.get(position).isTasksCompleted().equals("true"))
                    {
                        tasks.get(position).setTasksCompleted("false");                         
                    }
                    else if(tasks.get(position).isTasksCompleted().equals("false"))
                    {
                        tasks.get(position).setTasksCompleted("true");                          
                    }
                    updateThisTask(tasks.get(position));
                    tasks.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        v = convertView;
    }
    return v;
}

private void updateThisTask(Tasks tasks) {
    DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getContext());
    int id = dbAdapter.getID(tasks);
    dbAdapter.updateTask(tasks, id);
}

}
```

I want to remove item from the array list. As you can see I am using checkbox. The first time I click the checkbox, correct item is removed. The second time if I click the checkbox, the application crashes due to index out of bounds. How can I remove an item from the array list called tasks and update the listview?

Comment: your adapter is baseAdapter / ArrayAdapter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you remove an item from the `tasks` array, all of the items after that get a new index so all of the `position` values that you've saved in the holders and passed to the `OnCheckedChangeListener` are wrong. I fyou want to do this this way, you can't rely on using the position in the array as a way of finding an entry. You'll need to use the object itself and search the array to find the matching object. Use something like

```
int arrayIndexOfThisTask = tasks.indexOf(objectThatIsInTheArray);
```

**EDIT: Add code example:**

Try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.presenterlayout, null, false);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v.setTag(holder); // Attach the holder to the view so we can find it again
        holder.taskTitleTextView = (TextView)      v.findViewById(R.id.taskTitleTextView);
        holder.taskDescriptionTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskDescriptionTextView);
        holder.taskDueTimeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskDueTimeTextView);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder from the recycled view
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    // Get the task at this position in the array
    final Task task = tasks.get(position);

    holder.taskTitleTextView.setText(task.getTasksTitleString());
    holder.taskDescriptionTextView.setText(task.getTasksDescriptionString());
    holder.taskDueTimeTextView.setText(task.getTasksDueTimeString());
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(holder.checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                // Try to find the position in the array for this object (it may already have been removed)
                int position = tasks.indexOf(task);
                System.out.println("postion: " + position);
                // If this object is no longer in the array, just ignore this action
                if (position >= 0) {
                    if(tasks.get(position).isTasksCompleted().equals("true"))
                    {
                        tasks.get(position).setTasksCompleted("false");                         
                    }
                    else if(tasks.get(position).isTasksCompleted().equals("false"))
                    {
                        tasks.get(position).setTasksCompleted("true");                          
                    }
                    updateThisTask(tasks.get(position));
                    tasks.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

I may not have everything exactly right, but you should get the idea.

There were actually many things wrong with your code:

1. You weren't using the `ViewHolder` pattern correctly. You never attached the `ViewHolder` to the `View` itself by using `setTag()` and you never retrieved the `ViewHolder` from the `View` when given a recycled view in `convertView`.
2. If `convertView` was non-null you just returned it without doing anything with it. This is wrong because the adapter recycles views any way it wants to and it may pass you the `View` from position 6 and ask for a `View` for position 1. In this case you would have just returned the `View` for position 6 (which isn't correct).
3. I've passed the actual `Task` object into the `onCheckChanged()` method instead of passing the position and I've used `indexOf()` to get the current position in the array for that object.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This cannot be, because I will need some kind of index to get the item from the array list.

Comment: Added code example and a number of other observations. Have fun.

Comment: May I ask for a tutorial where the points you have stated are taken into consideration please.