# Update ListView on item delete or rename

Tags: java, android, listview

I have the following code in a tabbed `Fragment`:

```
    private SetRowsCustomAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<SetRows> rowsArray = new ArrayList<SetRows>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> current_file:filesInFolder.entrySet()) {
     rowsArray.add(new SetRows(R.drawable.ic_launcher, current_file.getKey().toString(), current_file.getValue().toString()));
        }
         adapter = new SetRowsCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.customlist, rowsArray);
     dataList = (ListView) mFrame3.findViewById(R.id.lvFiles);
     dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

getActivity().deleteFile(txt + ".trp");
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class).putExtra("tab", 2));
```

which deletes a row within my `ListView` and starts a new activity to show the changes. Although I have the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, it doesn't display the changes once a row is deleted without the last line on the code above.

Can someone please help me fix that so it shows the changes without starting a new activity.

Comment: you don't need the notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: I removed the last two lines but my ListView does not update unless I go out of the tab and come back to it again.

Comment: are you sure this adapter is the adapter for the list being viewed?

Comment: I updated the above code with more info. I am pretty sure it is.

Comment: what is funny is that when you reload the page it updates. it means the filesInfolder map is also updated.

Comment: Any idea how to do it without reloading the Fragment activity?

Comment: from your code, reloading should restore the original state, unless there is something else you are doing.

Comment: It reloads the activity, so when I press the Back button it goes back to the old activity again.

Comment: what i mean is, if you don't change the content of filesInFolder, there is no reason why reloading the view should display anything else but what is in filesInFolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of custom adapter is better for it, these link will help you for it
[Remove ListView items in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558591/remove-listview-items-in-android)
[How to remove arraylist item and then update listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251065/how-to-remove-arraylist-item-and-then-update-listview)

I think you require to delete from arraylist then call adapter setNotifyDataChange(), b'cos when you call this function it reload the adapter from arraylist.